# Pause AVPlayer in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, avplayer

I have an AVPlayer that streams audio from a URL when a row is selected in the table view. I'm trying to figure out how I can pause the audio if the same row is selected while the audio is playing.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *streamingString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.json?client_id=fc886d005e29ba78f046e5474e3fdefb", [streamURLArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSURL *streamingURL = [NSURL URLWithString:streamingString];
    selectedRow = indexPath.row;
    [tableView reloadData];
    player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:streamingURL];
    [player play];
    player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the selected `indexPath.row` is equal to your `selectedRow`.
If it is then do `[player pause];`